# What does "Charges" signify in this paragraph

Tags: single-word-requests

I was tasked to do the translation of this paragraph in my native language, but the particular highlighted word "charges" is bothering me. Any help will be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

From dictionary.com:

> charge
>
> ...
>
> noun
>
> ...
>
> 34. anything or anybody committed to one's care or management

It's referring to the "Tahitian converts" as charges because they are "in the care" of the missionaries. In fact, there's a more specific definition when someone is under the spiritual care of a religious leader:

> 35. *Ecclesiastical*. a parish or congregation committed to the spiritual care of a pastor.

Comment: Thank you, I got it. First I thought the word was a misfit but on other hand had this feeling that it was something much finer.

Comment: But, that's GR!